# Vertical alignment of beams for Percussion score

Tags: musixtex, musixper

It is needed to replicate the following score, the code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
\input {musixbm} % compatibilidad garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
\input {musixbbm} % compatibilidad semi garrapateas con ganchos o con barras

\begin{document}

\begin{music}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
    \font\B=phvb8t at 9pt% added for letter type.
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \nobarnumbers
    \setname1{Percussion}
    \setclefsymbol1\drumclef
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac24}
    \parindent15mm
    \nostartrule
    \def\writebarno{\A\the\barno}
    %\renewcommand*\writebarno{\textit{\the\barno}}%
    \scale{1.0}
    \startpiece 
    %1er compás
    \notes\loffset{2.8}{\zchar{12}{\metron{\qu}{\B74}}}\ql j\en
    \notes\ibbl0k0\qb0{jjj}\tqb0j\en\bar
    %2do compás: Voy alégre
    \notes\ql j\en
    \notes\ibbl1k0\roff{\tbbl1}\qb1j\en
    \notes\qb1j\en
    \notes\tbbl1\tbl1\qb1j\en\bar
    %Rápido saltaré
    \notes\ibl1j0\qb1j\enotes
    \notesp\nbbl1\qb1j\enotes
    \Notes\tbl1\qb1j\en
    %Saltaré
    \notes\ibbl3k0\qb3j\enotes
    \notesp\tbbl3\qb3j\enotes
    \Notes\tbl3\qb3j\enotes\bar 
    %Voy silencio
    \Notes\ql j\hsk\qp\en\bar
    %Corro ligerito
    \notes\ibl0j0\qb0{j}\tbl0\qb0j\en
    \notes\ibbl0k0\qb0{jjj}\tqb0j\en\bar
    %Saltaré Rápido
    %Saltaré
    \notes\ibbl3k0\qb3j\enotes
    \notesp\tbbl3\qb3j\enotes
    \Notes\tbl3\qb3j\enotes 
    %Rápido
    \notes\ibl1j0\qb1j\enotes
    \notesp\nbbl1\qb1j\enotes
    \Notes\tbl1\qb1j\en
    \systemnumbers
    \alaligne
    %Corro sálto
    \notes\ibl0j0\qb0{j}\tbl0\qb0j\en
    %Sálto
    \notes\ibl0j0\qbp0j%
    \roff{\tbbl0\tql0j}\sk\en\bar
    %Voy silencio
    \notes\ql j\hsk\qp\en\bar
    %Ligerito Ligerito
    \notes\ibbl0k0\qb0{jjj}\tqb0j\en
    \notes\ibbl0k0\qb0{jjj}\tqb0j\en\bar 
    %Rápido sálto
    \notes\ibl1j0\qb1j\enotes
    \notesp\nbbl1\qb1j\enotes
    \Notes\tbl1\qb1j\en
    %Sálto
    \notes\ibl0j0\qbp0j%
    \roff{\tbbl0\tql0j}\sk\en\bar
    %Rápido rápido
    \notes\ibl1j0\qb1j\enotes
    \notesp\nbbl1\qb1j\enotes
    \Notes\tbl1\qb1j\en
    \notes\ibl1j0\qb1j\enotes
    \notesp\nbbl1\qb1j\enotes
    \Notes\tbl1\qb1j\en\bar
    %Alégre voy
    %Alégre
    \notes\ibbl1k0\roff{\tbbl1}\qb1j\en
    \notes\qb1j\en
    \notes\tbbl1\tbl1\qb1j\en
    %Voy
    \notes\ql j\hsk\en
    \setdoubleBAR
    \Endpiece
  \end{music}
      
\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

The desired output is as follow (note that is needed a sligty vertical aligment on beams):
[image: desired]

Comment: You cannot say \ql{5.5}, \stemlength works only up to one beam (see manual}, and when you \raise the beams, the end of the stem is not connected to it anymore. You will have to search for the calculation of the stem length for two or more beams in musixtex.tex and adapt it …, or find another program that provides your preferent layout.